# java: Syntax error on token in polymorphic array

Tags: java, arrays, syntax, token

I'm trying to follow theNewBoston's java tutorial 55 Introduction to Polymorphism (from '09)

```
class apples {
public static void main(String[] args){


    food mark[]=new food[2];
    mark[0] = new potpie;
    mark[1] = new tuna;

    for(int x=0;x<2;++x){
        mark[x].eat();
    }
  }
}
```

I've copied the code exactly(I've checked 3 or so times now) but I keep getting this error at

```
mark[0] = new potpie;

Multiple markers at this line
- Syntax error on token(s), misplaced 
  construct(s)
- Syntax error on token ";", ( expected
- Syntax error on token ";", ( expected
```

I've got 4 classes counting the main one and the .eat method is just a println. Also when I run it i get

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)
Syntax error on token ";", ( expected
tuna cannot be resolved to a variable
```

Don't know if that helps but sometimes you never know.

Comment: The compiler TOLD YOU what you'd done wrong when it said `( expected`.  It's a good idea to actually read compile errors before you post them on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing parenthesis when you call new. Change

```
mark[0] = new potpie;
mark[1] = new tuna;
```

to

```
mark[0] = new potpie();
mark[1] = new tuna();
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use braces to indicate you are calling the constructor.

```
mark[0] = new potpie();
mark[1] = new tuna();
```